# Accurate browser datetime API

Tags: javascript, datetime

I assume the browser's native `new Date()` is subject to errors in the client computer's datetime.  In my current application, it would be easier if I can guarantee the datetime provided by a user's browser is acceptably accurate (i.e. +/- 3 seconds is fine).

Is there an API (via HTTP requests) that when queried, will return the current UTC date and time?

I don't mind if you have to sign up / spend money to use it / it's rate limited by origin.

I was imagining I might use the following code:

```js
let ms_diff: number | undefined = undefined
async function get_datetime ()
{
    if (ms_diff === undefined)
    {
        const start = new Date().getTime()
        const text = await fetch("https://example.com/current_datetime").text()
        const end = new Date().getTime()

        // Perhaps retry once or twice if difference between
        // `start` and `end` is too large.

        // approximate datetime of when request was received at API
        const simple_mean = (start + end) / 2

        ms_diff = new Date(text).getTime() - simple_mean
    }

    return new Date(new Date().getTime() + ms_diff)
}
```

Comment: I don't know about one, but you can always make an api for it if there isn't an existing one.

Comment: Yep @programmerRaj , I was hoping to avoid that if possible ;)

Comment: Most computers these days are configured to use NTP to keep the clock accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I found one: http://worldtimeapi.org/pages/examples.

I think the api easiest for you to implement is http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip . This is what it sends:

```
{
  "abbreviation": "PDT",
  "client_ip": "206.110.20.18",
  "datetime": "2021-09-13T08:32:18.636090-07:00",
  "day_of_week": 1,
  "day_of_year": 256,
  "dst": true,
  "dst_from": "2021-03-14T10:00:00+00:00",
  "dst_offset": 3600,
  "dst_until": "2021-11-07T09:00:00+00:00",
  "raw_offset": -28800,
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "unixtime": 1631547138,
  "utc_datetime": "2021-09-13T15:32:18.636090+00:00",
  "utc_offset": "-07:00",
  "week_number": 37
}
```

Warning: This is what the website says:

> It is not recommended that this API be used for commercial applications. The API can go down from time-to-time, for relatively long periods. It is provided with no SLA, no guarantees, and no direct funding.

http://worldtimeapi.org/pages/faqs#what-can-i-use-it-for